# Возможно ли переполнение List в моем случае?

Tags: java, android

Я реализовал метод, который читает контакты юзера и складывает их в `ArrayList<Friend> list` и получается ситуация, что в моей записной книге 300 контактов и так для того, чтоб заполнить массив методу приходиться создать 300 обьектов и сложить их в лист `list`

и я получаю вот такие сточки в логе:

> 07-27 16:20:39.663 18588-18698/com.fittingroom.newtimezone I/art:  Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7741(518KB) AllocSpace objects,  2(40KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 26MB/30MB, paused 1.294ms total 55.011ms
>   07-27 16:20:40.952 18588-18698/com.fittingroom.newtimezone I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18304(700KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 27MB/31MB, paused 1.207ms total 45.170ms
>   07-27 16:20:42.250 18588-18698/com.fittingroom.newtimezone I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 21419(816KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 27MB/31MB, paused 1.332ms total 52.736ms
>   07-27 16:20:43.519 18588-18698/com.fittingroom.newtimezone I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20440(782KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 27MB/31MB, paused 1.587ms total 53.310ms
>   07-27 16:20:44.782 18588-18698/com.fittingroom.newtimezone I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20851(799KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 27MB/31MB, paused 1.539ms total 53.030ms

Я почитал и понял, что это коллектор собирает то, что уже не нужно в процессе создания этих обьектов...

Вот вопрос в том, а что если у юзера допустим будет 1000 контактов?

Не вылетит ли приложение в этим случае?

И насколько правильно загружать сразу весь список? может стоит его грузить в `RecyclerView` по частям?

Подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю RecyclerView не будет загружать сразу все элементы, новые он загружает по мере сролла.

Comment: @KirillStoianov Да, но загружать он их будет из того `ArrayList` который содержит все эти контакты... Вопрос в том, нужно ли забирать все контакты с телефонной книги сразу себе или подгружать их частями?

Comment: Можно в ваш query добавить LIMIT, скажем 100, и по мере прокрутки(endless list) подгружать следующие 100 контактов

Comment: я пробовал загружать около 1000  контактов со всеми полями в один список для ListView и приложение не падало.

Comment: Мудрые говорили: разделяй и властвуй. Это актуально и по сей день. Даже на бесконечной памяти с бесконечной производительностью.

Comment: @DimXenon Не до конца понял ход мысли...

Comment: Цитата из http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php: "Курсоры.
В Android запросы к базе данных возвращают объекты класса Cursor. Вместо того чтобы извлекать данные и возвращать копию значений, курсоры ссылаются на результирующий набор исходных данных. Курсоры позволяют управлять текущей позицией (строкой) в результирующем наборе данных, возвращаемом при запросе." В данном случае можно делать выборку записей пачками в первоначальном запросе или делать полную выборку всех контактов и "ползать" курсором по небольшой выборке.

Comment: Главное не делать полные выборки, когда результатом будет копия данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` может принять `Integer.MAX_VALUE` элементов. на Земле не думаю, что все 2 147 483 647 имеют телефоны. так что ответ НЕТ, не переполнится

> И насколько правильно загружать сразу весь список? может стоит его грузить в >RecyclerView по частям?
>   зависит от скорости. если скорость считывания с памятью позволяют, то делай

Comment: Вот это и была суть моего вопроса)) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Грузить в RecyclerView информацию чатями нет никакого смысла, т.к. он сам забирает у адаптера ровно столько, сколько нужно ему элементов для отображения + 2 элемента дополнительно.. т.е. количество элементов в RecyclerView он регулирует сам общаясь с адаптером и зависит оно от размеров экрана.

Comment: Та вопрос не в том сколько элементов влезет в RecyclerView, а в том есть ли смысл заполнять адаптер для него сразу всеми контактами? Он все равно берет их частями, нужно ли грузить ему 10000 контактов, если он будет брать только по 10?